# On jQuery's datatables, how to run a line of code on table rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

https://www.datatables.net/

I need to run a line of js code after the datatable has rendered, is there an API setting to do that? 
I tried initComplete and this function gets executed after initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option to define a function that is called every time the table is redrawn.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
    }
} );
```